# Does yoga affect music?

Tags: experimental-psychology, music, anxiety, meditation, sport-psychology

I am currently studying for a bachelor's degree in psychology, as part of the degree, I was asked to conduct a study during which I will examine the interaction effect of yoga and music and their effect on anxiety.
In order to substantiate the research hypothesis, I must find a finding that shows that yoga affects music in some way, for example, that yoga increases the ability to pay attention to music.
Are you familiar with that kind of finding?

Comment: The question seems a bit vague. Have you tried browsing search results with terms like this?: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C50&q=yoga+music&btnG=

Comment: A good study would examine all the relevant information required to form an objective outcome. In your example, how beneficial is Yoga on its own against anxiety? How about music on its own? What kinds of music are more effective? Now what if you were to mix the music with Yoga. Is it more effective? What are the possible reasons based on research by you and/or others around Yoga practice and its effects?...

Comment: *"In order to substantiate the research hypothesis, I must find a finding that shows that yoga affects music in some way"*. To substantiate the facts, you need to provide evidence to support or prove the truth of your findings. Google Scholar can be your friend while trying to find relevant research backing or refuting your claims.

Comment: @BryanKrause
Sure, I've tried Google Scholar and this exact search but found nothing relevant (research/finding). I also thought there is no chance that I'll find such one since this question maybe doesn't much interesting. Do you think it could exist? I need to find facts that will support this claim- "Does yoga affect music?" without the anxiety part. Could you assist?

Comment: @ChrisRogers
Similar to my response from above, Google Scholar is my BFF these days, still, I didn't find any fact or something solid I can rely on regarding this specific claim.

Comment: I don't know, some of the results on the first page (that's as far as I looked) seemed quite relevant to me. Maybe not exactly what you're looking for but you need a more open mind in literature review. You don't necessarily need to find all the papers directly in search, but also in the citations of papers in the same general scope.